# Toggle a set of inputs on a form in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I have a form in a Rails application with an invite code and a block of credit card information.  I'd like to be able to toggle between the two on the same page.  Either the user provides an invite code **or** they input credit card information.  It would be nice if a one or the other could be hidden when inactive (but not necessary).  Here's the relevant bits of the form:

```
  %hr

  %fieldset
    .control-group
      = label_tag :invite_code, nil, :class => "control-label"

      .controls
        = text_field_tag :invite_code

    .control-group
      .controls
        = f.hidden_field :stripe_token
        = f.hidden_field :last_4_digits

    - if @user.last_4_digits
      .control-group
        = label_tag :card, nil, :class => "control-label"
        .controls
          Using card ending with #{@user.last_4_digits}
          = link_to "(change)", "#"

  %hr

  %fieldset
    %noscript
      %p
        This form requires Javascript to use

    .control-group#credit-card{ :style => @user.last_4_digits ? "display:none" : "display:block" }
      #credit-card-errors{:style => "display:none"}
        #stripe-error-message.alert-message.block-message.error

      .control-group
        = label_tag :credit_card_number, nil, :class => "control-label"
        .controls= text_field_tag :credit_card_number, params[:credit_card_number], :class => "field", :disabled => true 

      .control-group
        = label_tag :cvv, "Security code (CVV)", :class => "control-label"
        .controls= text_field_tag :cvv, params[:cvv], :class => "small", :disabled => true 

      .control-group
        = label_tag :expiry_date, nil, :class => "control-label"
        .controls= date_select "", :expiry_date, {:discard_day => true, :order => [:month, :year], :use_month_numbers => true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 25, :disabled => true}, {:class => "input-small"}

      /empty
      %p
        Subscriptions will be billed $12 annually.

  %fieldset.form-submit
    = submit_tag 'Sign up', :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary'
```

What is the sanest way to go about doing this?

Comment: Note that beyond the form, the app doesn't care which input is provided.  It's happy to roll along with or without one or the other.

Comment: Why not put them in tabs? Something like this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

Comment: do you know what the user will do upon entry? (is it in the link somehow?) otherwise - how do you want the "hiding" to be triggered?

Comment: Tabs may be confusing to the user as the target audience for this isn't terribly tech savvy.  

A radio button or a simple "Do you have an invite code?" question would suffice.  I even considered building two separate forms rather than trying to hide some of the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with adding CSS ids or classes to your different field sets

```
%fieldset#card
...
%fieldset#invite
...
```

use a CSS class called hidden

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

and add it as default on the invite fieldset

```
%fieldset#invite.hidden
```

then add your "have an invite?" link

```
%a{ :class => "have_invite" }
```

then some jquery along these lines

```
var show_invite_form = function(){
    $("#invite").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#card").addClass("hidden");
};
$(".have_invite").click(show_invite_form);
```

And if you want it a bit more fancy you can start looking at jquerys fade and animate methods.